# How to solve Model matching at /route/blah/ in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.8

**Hello, I am currently making a Django Application that makes use of django allauth and Google Auth**

`Issue is that when I login using django allauth and try to access the route /profile/view/`

`It throws this huge error at me, below is just the minified version`

For more help this is the code for the following files ...

`models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):


    COUNTRY_CHOICES = (
        ('No region selected ...', 'No region selected ...'),
        ('The Caribbean', 'The Caribbean'),
        ('Central America', 'Central America'),
        ('North America', 'North America'),
        ('South America', 'South America'),
        ('Oceania', 'Oceania'),
        ('Africa', 'Africa'),
        ('Europe', 'Europe'),
        ('Asia', 'Asia'),
    )


    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default="John")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default="Doe")
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default="FireCDN-User")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=240, blank=True, default="No informations provided ...")
    region = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default="No country selected ...", choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/avatars/', default="shared/avatar/default-avatar.png")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Profiles"

class FileUploads(models.Model):

    FILE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('No file type selected ...', 'No file type selected ...'),
        ('Stylesheets', 'Stylesheets'),
        ('JavaScript', 'JavaScript'),
        ('Documents', 'Documents'),
        ('Images/Pictures', 'Images/Pictures'),
        ('Scripts', 'Scripts'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="User Profile")
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='storage/files/', blank=False, null=False, validators=[
        FileExtensionValidator([
            # Image Files
            "tiff",
            "svg",
            "pdf",
            "raw",
            "webp",
            "gif",
            "heif",
            "heic",
            "psd",
            "ind",
            "indt",
            "indd",
            "png",
            "jpg",
            "jpeg",
            "jfif",
            "bmp",
            "dib",
            "pdf",
            "arw",
            "cr2",
            "nrw",
            "k25",
            "tif",
            "jfi",
            "jpe",
            "jif",
            "ai",
            "eps",
            "svgz"
            "jp2",
            "j2k",
            "jpf",
            "jpx",
            "jpm",
            "mj2"

            # Stylesheet Files
            "css",
            "less",
            "sass",
            "scss",

            # Scripts / JavaScript Files
            "py",
            "js",
            "ts",

            # Misc: (Microsoft Word)
            "docx",
            "txt",
        ])
    ], verbose_name="File Path")
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="File name needs to be provided!")
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=FILE_TYPE_CHOICES, default="no file type selected ...")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "File Uploads"
```

`views.py`

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import FileUploadsForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from user_profiles.models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = Profile.objects.get(username=user)
    form = FileUploadsForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/profile/files/list/")

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "profile": profile,
    }
    return render(request, "profiles/profile.html", context)

# Function to render 404 error
def page_not_found(request, exception):
    error_message_code = "404"
    error_message = "Not Found"
    context = {
        "error_code": error_message_code,
        "error_message": error_message,
    }
    return render(request, "shared/errors/404.html", context)

# Function to render 500 error
def server_error(request):
    error_message_code = "500"
    error_message = "Internal Server Error"
    context = {
        "error_code": error_message_code,
        "error_message": error_message,
    }
    return render(request, "shared/errors/500.html", context)

def file_uploads_list(request):
    file_uploads = Profile.objects.get(username=request.user)
    context = {

    }
    return render(request, "profiles/file-uploads/list.html", context)
```

`urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import profile_view, file_uploads_list

urlpatterns = [
    path('view/', profile_view, name='profile-view'),
    path('files/list/', file_uploads_list, name='file_uploads-view'),
]
```

`The error is below:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lokot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\lokot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lokot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lokot\Desktop\Django Applications\django-project-2\src\user_profiles\views.py", line 11, in profile_view
    profile = Profile.objects.get(username=user)
  File "C:\Users\lokot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lokot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 429, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /profile/view/
Exception Value: Profile matching query does not exist.
```

***Honestly I really need help because I have ran out of ideas to fix it ...***

> ***If you need more info just ask***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views.py...

```
user = request.user
profile = Profile.objects.get(username=user)
```

Is what's throwing the error. This will likely always happen if your user isn't authenticated, so you should use...

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
  user = ...
```

Also, request.user returns an AUTH_USER_MODEL. Your second line is querying whether a profile's username is equal to an AUTH_USER_MODEL. Instead, it should query for your user models' username.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    user = request.user.username
    profile = Profile.objects.get(username=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
user = request.user
profile = Profile.objects.get(username=user)
```

to

```
user = request.user.username
profile = Profile.objects.get(username=user)
```